# Cant make addition of array, no match for call to '(std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}) (std::string&, std::string&)'

Tags: c++

I have function in array and cant make the addition of it in main function because it wont 'allow'? can someone help me? The error: 154 no match for call to '(std::string {aka std::basic_string}) (std::string&, std::string&)'. If anyone wants to see the full code, please head to https://github.com/infaddil/beyblade/blob/main/newassver2.cpp

```
float type(string s4, string s3)
{
    float marks;
    if(s4 == "Attack")
        marks = 4;
    else if (s3 == "Balance")
        marks = 3;
    else if (s3 == "Attack")
        marks = 2;
    else if (s3 == "Defense")
        marks = 1;
        
    return marks;
}

cout << "Your mark is " << type(s4[randomnumber], s3[randomnumber]) << endl;
```

Comment: You probably have a string called `type` in the same scope. Pick better names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First line of your main():
string player1_name, player2_name, beyblade_name, product_code, **type**, plus_mode, system;

You defined **string** type,and your function is type too;

Add :: before type like this

```
cout << "Your mark is " << ::type(s4[randomnumber], s3[randomnumber]) << endl;
```

or pick another name.